# Sending XMPP IM message to a room

Tags: xmpp

I am trying to find out if it's possible to send a XMPP IM message to a room instead of individuals.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need should be defined in the [XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) extension standard.
For everything else you have to ask more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Sending message in group and sending individual message is different thing. Both handles in different ways. Although! You can send message in group using your room's object i.e. XMPPRoom (Specifically for iOS Client) as bellow:

```
        [XMPPRoom sendMessage:@"Your Message"];
```

For more information on XMPP MUC follow XEP-0045 doccument.